# Routing Error uninitialized constant ArticleController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby on rails.I written the code in app/controllers/articles_controler.rb

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)

  @article.save
  redirect_to @article
end

private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end
```

When i opened the rails server i got error as Routing Error uninitialized constant ArticleController.

In config/routes.rb I have the following code

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'articles/new'

  resources :article 

  root 'welcome#index'
 end
```

Comment: what do you have in your `config/routes.rb`?

Comment: do you a controller named `class ArticlesController < ApplicationController` ?

Comment: Post your full controller code.And as @WaliAli said controller names should be plural.

Comment: just like I thought, you have `resources :article`. and the name of your controller is `class ArticlesController`. right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Controller names are plural

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController #notice, it is Articles
```

This means, in your `config/routs.rb`, you need to have a route that maps to `articles` (plural).

this surely means, in your `config/routes.rb`, you have a `resources :article`. 
and so the route is being mapped to a controller named `Article`, which you don't have it, and which is incorrect anyway. this is why you are getting `Routing Error uninitialized constant ArticleController` because it can't find a controller named `Article` (singular)

It should be `resources :articles`. that way, it is going to look for a controller name `Articles`

bottom line: controller names are pluralized. so check your namings.

Comment: @VenkateshMandadi, you should accept this answer if it has resolved your question.

Answer (score 1):

Although `@Wali Ali` is right, there is something else to contend

Controllers *can* be singular - the convention is for plural controller names, but we use singulars for the likes of `exception` and some others. If you wanted to keep the name singular, you could just do:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :article # -> although not conventional, it will work

#app/controllers/article_controller.rb
class ArticleController < ApplicationController #-> name reflects route
```

---

[**Singular**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)

Something else you may want to look at is [singular routing resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources). These work very simply:

```
#config/routes.rb
resource :article

#app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
```

Although this is conventional, it means you'll have to keep the controller name as plural

This, coupled with `@Wali Ali`'s explanation, should help you solve it

Comment: thanks for sharing about singular resources. learned something new.

Comment: No problem! Can be very useful :)