# Rails routing error - uninitialized constant ArticlesController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I read the solutions to the problem on the following posts, but I couldn't apply them to my case:

- [Rails, uninitialized constant Getting Started with Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327038/rails-uninitialized-constant-getting-started-with-rails)
- [Routing Error uninitialized constant ArticleController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708325/routing-error-uninitialized-constant-articlecontroller/23708374#23708374)

I am working on a test blog and I wanted to create a page for new articles called 'new.html.erb'. Here is it's code:

```
<h1 align="center">Create an article</h1>
<% end %>
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
<p>
<%= f.label :title %><br/>
<%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.label :description %><br/>
<%= f.text_area :description %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

I also created a controller called 'articles.controller.rb':

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end
end
```

I added the following line in the 'routes.rb'

```
resources :articles
```

When I try to access /articles/new in my rails app, it shows:

> uninitialized constant ArticlesController

'$ rake routes' gives me the following output:

```
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
        root GET    /                            pages#home
 pages_about GET    /pages/about(.:format)       pages#about
    articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
             POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
 new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
     article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
             PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
```

Here is [my app on Github](https://github.com/niklbert/alpha-blog).

Answer (score 5):

Rename your controller

**`articles.controller.rb`** to **`articles_controller.rb`**

Your controller name must be underscore `_` separated.

Comment: Working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Your controller name is wrong.

It should be `articles_controller.rb` instead of `articles.controller.rb`